# Google Ads API does not return disabled campaigns

Tags: python, google-api, google-ads-api

I am migrating our API ingestion from `googleads` to `google-ads` in python and I noticed that the `campaign` resource only returns entities that have status "ENABLED". In the `googleads` version, it returns all entities by default when you request for it.

I tried modifying the GAQL to include filtering like `where campaign.status != 'ENABLED'` and I get no results back from the API.

Is there a way to get entities with all status like "PAUSED", "REMOVED" etc? Also, is there a place to run the GAQL in the web UI? (They have the GAQL validator but it doesn't let me run it)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can add in `WHERE` clause

```
campaign.status IN ('ENABLED', 'PAUSED', 'REMOVED', 'UNKNOWN')
```